# What is the proportional relation between effective length $L$ and gravitational acceleration $g$ for a simple pendulum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, length

The formula of time period of a simple pendulum stands for, T =2π √(L/g).

● If 2π and g remain constant, T would be proportional to the square root of L. Saying, T ∝ √L and T1/T2 would equal √(L1/L2).

If 2π and L remain constant, T would be inversely proportional to the square root of g. Saying, T ∝ 1/√g and T1/T2 would equal √(g2/g1).

Now, if T1/T2 equals T1/T2 then from equation-1 and equation-2, we can say that L1/L2 would equal g2/g1.

● But if T and 2π remain constant, then L becomes proportional to g. Saying L ∝ g and L1/L2 = g1/g2.

Now which one is correct in terms of math and which one is correct in terms of physics or where am i lagging?

[image: Attempt in finding out the proportional relation between L and g]

Comment: "Now, if T1/T2 equals T1/T2 then from equation-1 and equation-2, we can say that L1/L2 would equal g2/g1." What do you mean?

Comment: I meant, if left sides equal each other, the right sides would also do the same. @PhilipWood

Answer (score 0):

All the statements you've made are correct! Which one you use depends on what's staying constant ($T$, $L$, or $g$) in the problem you're trying to solve.

Note that $2\pi$ is always a constant.

Answer (score 0):

2pi is always a constant. Note that g and L are independent variables. You can't change the gravitational acceleration of a planet by changing the length of the pendulum. Nor can you change the length of the pendulum by changing the acceleration of gravity. Mathematically it's fine to say they are proportional. But physically, the more accurate expression is: given same period between two different pendulums, the ratio L/g between them is the same. Though that doesn't say much